# Anaconda Navigator Start Error on Macbook Air M2

Tags: anaconda, navigator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN1t3.jpg)

Navigator Start Error

Navigator Error

An unexpected error occurred on Navigator start-up

Report

Please report this issue in the anaconda issue tracker

Main Error

'bytes' object has no attribute 'get'

Traceback

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/themihirmathur/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anaconc return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/themihirmathur/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anaconc

window run_app (splash)

File "/Users/themihirmathur/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anaconc

window MainWindow (splash=splash)

File "/Users/themihirmathur/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anacond self.api AnacondaAPI()

File "/Users/themihirmathur/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anaconc ANACONDA_API = _AnacondaAPI()

File "/Users/themihirmathur/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anaconc

self._conda_api = CondaAPI()

File "/Users/themihirmathur/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anaconc

CONDA_API = _CondaAPI()

File "/Users/themihirmathur/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anaconc

self.set_conda_prefix(info=get_conda_info(allow_fixes=True)) File "/Users/themihirmathur/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/anaconc self.ROOT_PREFIX= info.get('root_prefix') # str

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'get'

Tried-

Navigator error on start up
This is often the result of a corrupted .condarc file. To resolve, delete the .condarc file and restart Navigator.

Find the .condarc file.

In Anaconda Prompt or the terminal, enter the command conda info. The output will tell you the location of your .condarc file(s). You can also search for “.condarc” on your computer.

The .condarc file is frequently found in:

macOS: /Users/

Linux: ~/.condarc

Windows: C:\Users\

Optional: Save custom configurations.

If you had custom configuration in your .condarc file before it was corrupted, save the information to add that configuration back to the new file.

Delete the .condarc file.

Restart Navigator.

Expecting-
A solution for this